# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have set up nodeIntegration as true in index.js where I am creating the browserwindow.

```
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width:900,
    height:900,
    webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration:true
        }
});
```

However, when I am trying to reference a js file in my index.html page it throws "require is not defined"

```
<script src="js/Jobs.js"></script>
<script>
function expand()
{
    //my code here

}
</script>
</head>
```

> Jobs.js
>
> const $ = require('jquery');

Electron version: 8.3.1

Comment: Did you reload the dev server (webpack) after adding `nodeIntegration:true` to the main file?

Comment: @alex-hoffman..Yes  I did that! but no luck

Comment: I was using Iframe in index.html, so this issue was resolved by adding  "nodeIntegrationInSubFrames:true" in webPreferences